# How do I avoid division by zero error?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a code like this:

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_flash2', 'lx_custom_onsale_label', 10, 2 );
  function lx_custom_onsale_label() {
    global $product;

    $percentage = round( ( ( $product->get_regular_price()  - $product->get_sale_price() ) / $product->get_regular_price()  ) * 100 );
    $absolute = round( ( ( $product->get_regular_price()  - $product->get_sale_price() ) ) );

    if ($product->get_regular_price()  > 100) {
    return '<span class="onsalex bg_primary headerfont">'. sprintf( __(' -%s', 'salex' ), $absolute . ',-' ).'</span>';
    } 

    else if ($product->get_regular_price()  < 1) {
    return '<span class="onsalessszzzx bg_primary headerfont">'. sprintf( __(' -%s', 'salex' ), $absolute . ',-' ).'</span>';
    }   

    else {
    return '<span class="onsalexzzz bg_primary headerfont">'. sprintf( __(' -%s', 'salex' ), $percentage . '%' ).'</span>';
    }
}
```

Everything work fine except when the divider is O, the notify will show:

> Warning: Division by zero in
>   D:\SERVER\InstantWP_4.3.1\iwpserver\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\MYTHEME\functions.php on line 553

Line 553 is this code:

```
    $percentage = round( ( ( $product->get_regular_price()  - $product->get_sale_price() ) / $product->get_regular_price()  ) * 100 );
```

I don't understand how to avoid the warning with the condition zero on that code.

Really appreciate for the help.

Comment: Cheeky answer: *Don't divide by zero*

Comment: Just test if `$product->get_regular_price()`  is greater than 0 before doing the operation

Comment: `if` comes really handy IF you don't want to do something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace :

```
$percentage = round( ( ( $product->get_regular_price()  - $product->get_sale_price() ) / $product->get_regular_price()  ) * 100 );
```

by :

```
$percentage = 0;
if ( $product->get_regular_price() > 0 ) 
    $percentage = round( ( ( $product->get_regular_price()  - $product->get_sale_price() ) / $product->get_regular_price()  ) * 100 );
```

Strange answer I know, but if you don't divide by zero, there is no error.

**Explain** :

As @domdom point out "*Don't divide by zero*" which is here a good answer, and a good practice since divide by zero is not "legal" in mathematics.

Comment: Then please validate the answer by using the checkmark under the upvote button. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if($product->get_regular_price()> 0)
{
//do your work
}
```

Just check if the price is zero before the division.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if `$product->get_regular_price()` is greater than/ not equal to zero (in case negative values are possible):

```
if ($product->get_regular_price() != 0){
  // Do stuff
} else {
  // Do something with the zero
}
```

With only positive numbers:

```
if ($product->get_regular_price() > 0){
  // Do stuff
} else {
  // Do something with the zero
}
```

Comment: The answer above is work, but I also try your code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
 $percentage = round( ( ( $product->get_regular_price()  - $product->get_sale_price() ) / $product->get_regular_price()  ) * 100 );
```

with

```
 $percentage = $product->get_regular_price() != 0 ? round( ( ( $product->get_regular_price()  - $product->get_sale_price() ) / $product->get_regular_price()  ) * 100 ) : 0;
```

The question has been answered already, this is just another approach using the tenary operator

Answer (score -1):

try it. something like this is simple but useful..

```
$var = @($val1 / $val2);
```

Comment: working in php <8, not working in php >= 8.0 